# Pandas Matplotlib: How to change shape and size of the legend in scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot :

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5),dpi=200)

ax.scatter(df1['id'],df1['resellers'],c='red',s=df1['ips']/80,label='AS Size = IPs seen in dnsdb')
ax.set_xticks([1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20])
ax.set_xlim(-1,22)
ax.legend(
       scatterpoints=1,
   loc='best',
   ncol=1,
   fontsize=12)
```

I am wondering how can I change the shape and size of the bubble in the legend to rectangular and smaller size. Can anybody help?[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the size of the symbol in the legend using the `markerscale` keyword. For example,

```
ax.legend(
       scatterpoints=1,
   loc='best',
   ncol=1,
   markerscale=0.5,
   fontsize=12)
```

will reduce the symbol size by a factor 2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I also change the color of the symbol in case I am using heatmap the color of the symbol is on the default.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to change the color of the symbols (I also don't exactly understand why you would do it; if the color in the legend is different than the color in the plot, it kind of defeats the purpose of a legend)

Comment: Can one add 3 or 4 discs with different size to highlight the intensity?